# Trim first few characters from front with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table in mysql with column `comp_post_code` in whivh postcode format is with no space `M4W1A3` but some of the postcodes are like this with `AB T1H2J1`, `BC V6X3P7`, `QC G0C2R0` and so on.I want to remove this extra bit of AB BC from them.

how can i do that in mysql ... (`AB BC QC is just example there r many others in them, but all are in front and with space and postcode dont have space`)

EDIT ... I tryed this

```
UPDATE canada_database
SET comp_post_code= SUBSTRING(comp_post_code, 3)
```

But its deleting 1st 3 from all rows ... as i have mention there are some with this problem not all .. if i  do this it will affect all .

Comment: @Harinder - couldn't you select the final six characters instead?

Comment: Why not prepare your string in php with a function like `strpos()`?

Comment: @andrewsi yes we can do that but there is a problem in that because these are Canadian post codes ... it may be upto 7 or 8 characters i am not sure about that and i have big database ... so i am not sure about that

Comment: @Harinder - I thought Canadian postcodes were always six characters? Ah, it is according to Canada Post: http://www.canadapost.ca/tools/pg/manual/PGaddress-e.asp#1413985

Comment: @andrewsi yaa than we can select last six ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE canada_database SET comp_post_code = substring_index( comp_post_code, ' ', -1 )
```

Manual: [substring_index()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

See an example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/530db/1/0).

Comment: This is no better than the OP's code, see their comment: "as i have mention there are some with this problem not all .. if i do this it will affect all" - same thing with your code. Also, code without explanation isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

as an alternave way... you can select your data with regexp query...

```
select * from canada_database where comp_post_code regexp '[A-Z]{2} [A-Z]*';
```

then iterate througt them and update each with PHP... cause mysql doesn't support regexp-based replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE canada_database
SET comp_post_code = if(LOCATE(' ',comp_post_code) > 0 , SUBSTRING(comp_post_code , 3) , comp_post_code)
```